# Asynchronous programming in .Net Console application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, console-application

I have an application to unzip a folder and merge files, i want to use asynchronous here, i want a thread to unzip a folder and another thread to merge the files in unzipped folder, once the unzip thread complete its task, the app should wait for merger thread to complete. Merger thread(child) is dependent on unzip thread(parent)
below is the code i am using
inside program.cs file

```
var t1= Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {                       
       obj.UnZipFiles(files, formats);
    });
```

inside unzip.cs file

```
var t2= Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        obj.MergeFiles();
    });
```

In the program.cs file, I have

```
Task.WaitAll(t1);
```

My application is not waiting for child thread to complete, 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If step 2 can happen only after step 1 there is no concurrency and no asynchrony. Are you sure you understand the problem? Sounds like you're starting with a solution to a not-existing problem.

Comment: What "child thread" are you talking about? Btw. we're dealing with *`Task`s* here, not threads.

Comment: @usr consider an example: 2 zip folders having 10 files each, i want the app to complete unzipping of first zip folder and start merging 10 files in it, & in parallel it should start unzipping second zip folder,while the app is merging the files from first zip folder

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the second task, use Continuation.

E.g.

```
var t1 = new Task(() => obj.UnZipFiles(files, formats));
var t2 = t1.ContinueWith((t) => obj.MergeFiles());
t1.Start();
```

This will ensure the second task only gets triggered when the first task is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i guess this would make tasks syncronous, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Kiran_Ray from my understanding, this is going to be a "sort of" synchronous processing, because the second task will run on a different thread when the first task is ended. If you pass in `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` then the second task will run on the same thread as first making it really synchronous.

Comment: @Kiran_Ray On the other hand if you need to wait for the outcome of first task because you cannot do anything else before the first task is complete... Then maybe there's not much point in using tasks?

Comment: Below example will give you clear picture
2 zip folders having 10 files each, i want the app to complete unzipping of first zip folder and start merging 10 files in it, & in parallel it should start unzipping second zip folder,while the app is merging the files from first zip folder